# Creating subtotals with rollup in order

Tags: sql-server

I have the below data set, which is the datetime, tank and the weight.
I would like to add a subtotal of weight for each tank and for each day (sorting of tanks based on the datetime.

So the desired outcome would have a row at the end of each section of days for the subtotal, which would give a total for day 1 and then again for day 2

```
datum                   tk          gewicht
20/01/2018 9:00         TK1         1000
20/01/2018 10:00        TK1         2000
20/01/2018 4:00         TK10        3000
20/01/2018 8:00         TK2         4000
21/01/2018 6:00         TK3         5000
21/01/2018 7:00         TK5         6000
```

My query so far gives following result:

```
select cast(datum as datetime) as date, tk, sum(gewicht) as weight
  from tblReclassificatie 
group by rollup(tk,cast(datum as datetime)) 


date                    tk          weight
20/01/2018 9:00         TK1         1000
20/01/2018 10:00        TK1         2000
NULL                    TK1         3000
20/01/2018 4:00         TK10        3000
NULL                    TK10        3000
20/01/2018 8:00         TK2         4000
NULL                    TK2         4000
21/01/2018 6:00         TK3         5000
NULL                    TK3         5000
21/01/2018 7:00         TK5         6000
NULL                    TK5         6000
NULL                    NULL        21000
```

But the order is wrong - first is tk10 then tk2 not tk1 as first

Comment: This is because your datatype is character data and it sorts by the characters. You either need another way to sort your data or isolate just the number portion, cast that as an int and sort on that.

Comment: You have no order by in your query. In that case, the SQL standard does not guarantee any sort order, even if SQL server often (but not always) delivers some order. You need to add an `order by` after your `group by`.

Comment: Put effort into formatting.  Post the actual query.

Answer (score 0):

This query solves my problem (with new id field):

select [Date], tk, weegbon, gewicht, weeklotnr, id
from
(select [Date], tk, weegbon, sum(gewicht) as gewicht, min(datum) as Datum, min(weeklotnr) as weeklotnr, min(id) as id
from
       (select cast(datum as date) as [Date],
             datum,
             tk,
             weegbon,
             gewicht, 
             weeklotnr, 
             id
       from tblReclassificatie )a
group by [Date], tk , weegbon with rollup)aa
order by Datum, [Date],tk, weegbon